# Approach to a custom rails logger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, logging, ruby-on-rails-5

My Rails application runs in Heroku; recently, we have changed the Heroku LOG_LEVEL to WARN as the system logs flooded with so many unwanted information. But still, in some of the areas, I wanted to use Rails.logger.info;

Currently, in Heroku we have this:

```
LOG_LEVEL = WARN
```

And in production.rb, still that is

```
config.log_level = :info
config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
```

The above configuration we didn't change it, as the precedence is for LOG_LEVEL if we set that. So with the above configuration, if we put `Rails.logger.info "Hello world,"` that will not work because the logger will only handle the logs equal or higher to warn in importance.

So we have tried one other way.

Created a new initializer called `custom_logger.rb`; we put

```
$INFO_LOGGER = Rails.logger.dup
$INFO_LOGGER.level = :info
```

then wherever we wanted to use info, we just called `$INFO_LOGGER.info "Hello World,"` this prints

Is this a correct approach, like using the global variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a correct approach, like using the global variable?

This question could be considered opinion based, so in my opinion I would not recommend it. Additionally the question posed in the title is regarding a custom logger and while we could implement one to facilitate the request I would propose a simpler solution that will still log exactly what you want, to the current log file, and without the need for a custom logger, a secondary logger, or any kind of global variable.

**My Suggestion:**

Rails uses `ActiveSupport::Logger` by default which is essentially just a ruby `Logger`.

If there are messages you always want logged regardless of the `level` you can use `Logger#unknown`.

Per the [Documents](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#method-i-unknown) for the `Logger` class:

> Levels:
>
> UNKNOWN - An unknown message that should always be logged.
>
> Logger#unknown
>
> Log an UNKNOWN message. This will be printed no matter what the logger's level is.

So You can use this to your advantage for the messages that you always want to show while still avoiding the noise of the standard info messages:

For Example:

```
Rails.logger.info "Noisy message" # won't show when LOG_LEVEL > INFO 
Rails.logger.unknown "VERY IMPORTANT MESSAGE" # will show no matter what the level is set to
```

Comment: thanks @enginersmky, you mean in this line: Rails.logger.info "Noisy message" # won't show when LOG_LEVEL > WARN not LOG_LEVEL > INFO right?

Comment: @Developer there are 5 log levels in DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, and FATAL (technically 6 if you include UNKNOWN). These levels and their corresponding methods control what gets logged. If the severity of the message is greater than the log level it will get logged. So if the log level is greater than INFO e.g. WARN, ERROR, etc. Then info messages will not be logged

Comment: Hi @engineersmnky,  https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#impact-of-logs-on-performance, as per this content, do we need to use it like Rails.logger.unknown { "VERY IMPORTANT MESSAGE #{data}" }

Comment: @Developer No. The reason rails suggests that is because if the log level is above the message level then the block will not be executed which is better for performance because then it will skip evaluating the contents of the block. This is not needed for UNKNOWN messages be cause these messages will always be logged and thus the block will always be executed. This means that using a block with an unknown message will actually have a slight negative performance impact vs just the String itself.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use global variables. Instead create a custom class for example

```rb
class MyLogger
  class << self 

    def info(*args)
      new.info(*args)
    end
  end

  delegate :info, to: :logger 

  attr_reader :logger

  def initialize
    @logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(Rails.root.join("log/my_logger.#{Rails.env}.log"))
    @logger.formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  end
end
```

Now you can call `MyLogger.info("this is a test message")` and it will output the message in the log file regardless of the `LOG_LEVEL` or `config.log_level = :info`

Comment: Hi @Chris thanks for this, but I have one question, this will create a new log file called log/my_logger.production.log right?, is that correct way? Also where can we keep this class, is it somewhere under the lib folder?

Comment: Yes that correct but you can also log to `production.log` thats up to you. I would put this class in `app/lib` so it will be auto loaded by rails and no need to require it when you want to use it